# If $f$ has both one-way limits on $[a,b]$ , then $f$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Assume that $f$ is a function which has one-way limits at each point of $[a,b]$.

Question :

1. Prove that $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$.
2. Give an example of a function like $g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $g$ has one of one-way limits on each point of $[a,b]$ but $g$ is not bounded on $[a,b].$

Note 1 : "One-way limits" means limit from left and from right.

Note 2 : About Q1, I don't know how to make a relation between "being bounded" and "having one-way limits". If the function was continous, It was easy. But we don't know that.

Note 3 : About Q2, I have no image of that kind of function. I'm confused that how can this happen...

Note 4 : I don't know anything about compactness so please don't use that in your answers or hints.

Any answers or even hints would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint for Q1: assume the converse and use that $[a,b]$ is compact.

Comment: If both one-sided limits of $f$ exist at $x_0$, then $f$ is bounded on some neighbourhood of $x_0$. Have you already learned what "compact" means?

Comment: @DanielFischer I know about a theorem which states that if the values of a function is between values of two another functions, and that two functions have equal limits like $L$, then the first function's limit is $L$ ,too ... is that what you meant ?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. (That is the squeeze, or sandwich, theorem, it has nothing to do with compactness.)

Comment: @DanielFischer So, would you please explain that thing you call "compactness"?

Comment: This is not an appropriate venue to teach new concepts to you, that would require too much space (and time). If you haven't learned about compactness yet, we'll simply use another way to reach the conclusion. But keep the word in the back of your mind, and when it comes up in a course, be aware that it is a really really, _really_ useful concept.

Comment: So, without (explicitly) using compactness. Consider the set $B = \{ x \in [a,b] : f \text{ is bounded on } [a,x]\}$. Let $s = \sup B$. Show a) $s\in B$, and b) $s = b$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sure i'll be careful when we reached there ... So, I'm gonna edit my question and add that i want a method without using "compactness"

Comment: @DanielFischer What do you mean by "a) s" and "b) s"?

Comment: Part a) is "$s\in B$", and part b) is "$s = b$".

Comment: @DanielFischer I think i know the idea behind your way, What should i do now ? delete the question ?

Comment: You could also post an answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer OK, so i'm gonna write it in a formal way and then i'll post an answer ... thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ is not bounded,then for each $n\in \Bbb N$ $\exists x_n\in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_n)>n$.

Since $x_n\in [a,b] $ so we can find a convergent sequence of $x_n$ say $x_{n_k}$ converging to some $x_0$(say).

Since $[a,b]$ is closed so $x_0\in [a,b]$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)<\infty(=L)$(say).

So we can find a $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<1$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta \rightarrow (1)$.

Also since $x_{n_k}\to x$ all the terms of the sequence lie in $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ and at each term $f(x)$ is unbounded which contradicts $(1)$.

Hence $f$ is bounded

Comment: Thanks ! No idea about Q2 ?

Comment: Is this clear @IStillHaveHope?

Comment: Yes this is clear ... But i'm still stuck on the example